# Updating the versioning of the Azure DevOps extension

Tags: azure-devops, devops, pipeline, vscode-extensions, ado

I have an Azure DevOps extension and assume that the version number is 0.0.5, let us assume that I am adding a new minor feature(in task.json file), so ideally I would be modifying the version number to 0.0.6 (in both task.json file and vss-extension.json which is the manifest file).

But when I publish and try using the extension the marketplace wont allow me to publish and would ask me to change to a higher version number.

So next time I tried changing the minor version number(to 0.1.0), and I was able to publish successfully.

But the new features were not getting reflected, when I tried to use the task as extension.

Interestingly when I update the major version number for ex(to 1.0.0 from 0.0.5) I was able to see my new features.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to share more information about this issue. How you define the code in task.json and vss-extension.json? You can share a sample with us.